# ent.go saying sql: databse is closed on any query

Tags: sql, go, ent

`db/db.go`

```
    func DbClient(cfg *config.Config, logger log.Logger) *ent.Client {
    // "host=<host> port=<port> user=<user> dbname=<database> password=<pass>"
    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s dbname=%s password=%s",
        cfg.DB_HOST, cfg.DB_PORT, cfg.DB_USER, cfg.DB_NAME, cfg.DB_PASS)
    client, err := ent.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()
    logger.Info("Database Connected")
    if err := client.Schema.Create(context.Background()); !errors.Is(err, nil) {
        logger.Fatalf("Error: failed creating schema resources %v\n", err)
    }

    return client
}
```

`services/userservice.go`

```
func CreateUser(client *ent.Client, input *model.NewUser) (*ent.User, error) {
    user, err := client.Debug().User.Create().SetName(input.Name).SetUsername(input.Username).SetEmail(input.Email).SetPassword(input.Password).Save(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        return &ent.User{}, err
    }
    return user, nil
}
```

ent client creating all necessary tables and showing database is connected.
But when I am executing `CreateUser()` it is returning `sql: database is closed`. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a database connection `Close` call in your bootstrap code:

```
func DbClient(cfg *config.Config, logger log.Logger) *ent.Client {
  // "host=<host> port=<port> user=<user> dbname=<database> password=<pass>"
  psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s dbname=%s password=%s",
cfg.DB_HOST, cfg.DB_PORT, cfg.DB_USER, cfg.DB_NAME, cfg.DB_PASS)
  client, err := ent.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
  if err != nil {
      logger.Fatal(err)
  }
  defer client.Close() // <- this one
  logger.Info("Database Connected")
  if err := client.Schema.Create(context.Background()); !errors.Is(err, nil) {
    logger.Fatalf("Error: failed creating schema resources %v\n", err)
  }
  return client
}
```

This call close connection after returning `client`.
If it necessary to close a connection, close it in from the `CreateUser()` func.

```
func CreateUser(client *ent.Client, input *model.NewUser) (*ent.User, error) {
    user, err := client.Debug().User.Create().SetName(input.Name).SetUsername(input.Username).SetEmail(input.Email).SetPassword(input.Password).Save(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        return &ent.User{}, err
    }
    defer client.Close() // <- here
    return user, nil
}
```